# Joystick UI does not follow player/camera

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I have my onscreen joystick working exactly how I want it... except it goes off screen. I am EXTREMELY new to unity and only know what I am doing through google/YouTube tutorials, but google/YouTube couldn't help me this time! (Likely due to me using terrible terminology). Please give me suggestions! Thank you!

What I have tried:

I have attempted all 3 canvas render modes - to no avail.
I have tried the joystick as a child to the camera, player, etc - no avail

Here is an Gif of my issue:
https://gfycat.com/plasticperiodicflyingsquirrel

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class Joystick : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public float speed = 5.0f;
    private bool touchStart = false;
    private Vector2 pointA;
    private Vector2 pointB;
    public Transform circle;
    public Transform outerCircle;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            pointA = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
            circle.transform.position = pointA * 1;
            outerCircle.transform.position = pointA * 1;
            circle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
            outerCircle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            touchStart = true;
            pointB = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
        }
        else
        {
            touchStart = false;
        }
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (touchStart)
        {
            Vector2 offset = pointB - pointA;
            Vector2 direction = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(offset, 1.0f);
            moveCharacter(direction * 1);
            circle.transform.position = new Vector2(pointA.x + direction.x, pointA.y + direction.y) * 1;
        }
        else
        {
            circle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
            outerCircle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
        }
    }
    void moveCharacter(Vector2 direction)
    {
        player.Translate(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should draw the Joystick on a canvas. The canvas will always stretch from 0/0 to 1/1, independent of the 2D/3D camera's position. If you do have a 3D joystick, you might want to update its position according to the camera.

Comment: What if you use this rendering mode? Screen Space-Overlay mode: I personally think it is the mode closest to the concept of GUI. In fact, the UI is always in front of the 3D scene, and if the screen size is changed, the Canvas will also match.